# Issue with clearing state from an ngrx/redux store when the user logs out

Tags: ngrx, reselect, ngrx-effects

My application uses **ngrx/rxjs**. I rely on an ngrx effect in order to signout and clear state from the store.

Unfortunately, because one of my components subscribes to the store through a selector (see below: `getLatestMessagesByCounterParty`) and because the state is cleared before this component is destroyed, I get the following error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null
>       at getCurrentUserAccountId

... indicating that the `currentUserAccount` is `null`, which is quite logical since I have just cleared the state from the store.

Here is the `signout$` effect:

```
  @Effect()
  signout$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(authenticated.ActionTypes.SIGNOUT)
    .switchMap(() =>
      this.sessionSignoutService.signout()
        .do(() => {
          localStorage.removeItem('authenticated');
          localStorage.removeItem('sessionToken');
        })
        .concatMap(() => [
          new ClearMessagesAction(null),
          new ClearUserAccountAction(null),//Error thrown here...
          go(['/signin'])//Never reached...
        ]));
```

Here is the component that subscribes to the logged-in state:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.select(fromRoot.getLatestMessagesByCounterParty)
      .subscribe(latestMessages => this.latestMessages = this.messageService.sortMessagesByDate(latestMessages, this.numberOfConversations));
  }
```

And the relevant selectors:

```
...
const getCurrentUserAccountId = (state: State) => state.userAccount.currentUserAccount.id;
const getMessagesState = (state: State) => state.message.messages;

...
export const getLatestMessagesByCounterParty = createSelector(getCurrentUserAccountId, getMessagesState, fromMessage.latestMessagesByCounterParty);
```

I am looking for best practices on where, when and how to clear state from the store. Ideally I would like to do that at the last possible time, when the subscribing components have been destroyed.

Can someone please advise?

**edit**: Let me further refine my comment. My code above should have read as follows.

```
   .concatMap(() => [
      new ClearMessagesAction(null),
      new ClearUserAccountAction(null),//Error thrown right after this action because selector cannot find id variable on state
      go(['/signin'])//Never reached...
    ]));
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to add a `filter(account => !!acount)` somewhere

Comment: Hello Cgatian. Thanks for your reply. I am wondering whether there would not be a better practice to proceed than adding filters...

Comment: Hello Cgatian: can you please provide an example on how to add a filter on a selector?

Answer (score 0):

As @cgatian said, you might use a filter. But here's what would happen behind the scene with that code :

```
.concatMap(() => [
  new ClearMessagesAction(null),
  new ClearUserAccountAction(null),//Error thrown here...
  go(['/signin'])//Never reached...
]));
```

You'd first dispatch an action `ClearMessagesAction(null)`.
Then that action will be handled by your reducer.
___A new state will be produced
___Your selectors will be triggered right after
___An error will occur because you end up with an inconsistent store (*as you expect that the other action `ClearUserAccountAction(null)` was dispatched as the same time and before the selectors kick in*)

What you should do to avoid state inconsistency, is either :
 - Create **one** action that you handle in both reducers. This way, your reducers will both be modified and only then, selectors will kick in
 - Use a library that allows you to dispatch multiples actions as one (like [redux-batched-actions](https://github.com/tshelburne/redux-batched-actions)). This way you could write something like that :

```
batchActions([
  new ClearMessagesAction(null), --> selectors not triggered yet
  new ClearUserAccountAction(null) --> selectors not triggered yet
]); --> selectors triggered now
```

Comment: Thanks Maxime. Can you please provide a sample filter? Should the filter go in the selector?

Comment: Sure. Instead of passing your selector to `this.store.select`, use the  `let` operator. It allows you to get the whole observable. Here's an [example](https://gitlab.com/linagora/petals-cockpit/blob/5809ca8deade4b43595e50e0b69ef05cfbc91159/frontend/src/app/features/cockpit/workspaces/state/buses/buses.selectors.ts#L27). Then simply call `this.store.let(yourSelector)`